# iOS : need inputs in developing efficient ( performance wise ) drawing app

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimageview, calayer, quartz-graphics

I have this app using which one can draw basic shapes like rectangle, eclipse, circle, text etc.
I also allow free form drawing, which is stored as set-of-points, on the canvas.

Also a user can resize and move around these objects by operating on the selection handles that appear when an object is selected.
In addition the user should be able to zoom and pan the canvas.

I need some inputs on how to efficiently implement this drawing functionality.
I have following things in mind -

1. Use UIView's InvalidateRect and drawRect

Have a UIView for the main canvas and for each inserted object - invalidate the correspoding rect and redraw all the objects which intersects that rect in the drawRect function of the UIView.

1. Have a UIView and use CALayer ? 
   every one keep mentioning about the CALayer , I dont have much idea on this, before I venture into this I wanted a quick input on whether this route is worth taking.
   like, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1708/_index.html
2. Have a UIImageView as canvas and when drawing each object, we do this 
   i) Draw the object into offscreen CGContext, basically, create a new CGContext by using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, draw the shape, extract the image out of this CG context and use that as source of UIImageView's image property, but here how do I invalidate only a part of the UIImageView so that only that area gets refreshed.

Could you please suggest what is the best approach? 
Is there any other efficient way to get this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a UIImage is more efficient for rendering multiple objects. But Using a CALayer is more efficient when moving and modifying a single object because you don't have to modify the other objects. So I think the best approach is to use a UIImage for general drawing and a CALayer for the shape that is being modified. In other words:

- use a CALayer to draw the shape being added or modified, but don't draw it on the UIImage
- use a UIImage to draw the other shapes

But OpenGL is still the most efficient solution, but don't bother with that if you don't have too many objects to draw.

Comment: thanks for the info. When you say "use a CALayer to draw the shape being added or modified" you mean add a layer for each object? or have a single layer which acts as a canvas for all objects? if it is later, lets say i need to move an object around, i need to clear the current bounds and then redraw the object in the new bounds rt ? i am assuming that is an efficient way.Also, i have a background for the canvas, lets say its a set of horizontal lines, which doesnt change, so this would be  layer of its own rt ? iOS will take care of composting these layers into final view rt ?

Comment: Let's say you have an array containing all the shapes. Draw your background in a layer. Draw all off the shapes except the shape being modified now in a layer oldShapes. Draw the shape being added or modified in a separate layer currentShape. This way, you redraw the oldShapes layer only a few times. And when the user is modifying a shape, you have only to handle that shape. If for example you want to move the shape, simple move the layer or redraw the shape in the new coordinates.

Comment: Just wanted to add more info , the canvas extends beyond the screen size, the height of the canvas could be say 3000 pt , so i need to provide a way to pan and zoom/in/out the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw polygons, you'll have to use `Quartz` framework, and have your drawing methods based on `CALayer`. It doesn't really matter which view you'll put your `CALayers` in, `UIImageView` or `UIView`. I'll say `UIView` since you won't be needing `UIImageView`'s properties or methods for drawing.